# Pyspark: adding incremented value when certain condition is met

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

There might already be a simple way / function to do this, but here goes:
I need to filter "delta" by a condition (say if delta >10, the row is invalid), and then add a new column (say "continuity") in which the elements will increment by 1 each time an invalid row in "delta" is detected over the "person".

input df:

| person | delta |
| --- | --- |
| X | 2 |
| X | 3 |
| X | 4 |
| X | 20 |
| X | 50 |
| X | 5 |
| Y | 1 |
| Y | 20 |
| Y | 2 |
| Y | 3 |
| Z | 9 |
| Z | 30 |
| Z | 2 |
| Z | 15 |
| Z | 3 |

expected output df:

| person | delta | continuity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 2 | 1 |
| X | 3 | 1 |
| X | 4 | 1 |
| X | 20 | null |
| X | 50 | null |
| X | 5 | 2 |
| Y | 1 | 1 |
| Y | 20 | null |
| Y | 2 | 2 |
| Y | 3 | 2 |
| Z | 9 | 1 |
| Z | 30 | null |
| Z | 2 | 2 |
| Z | 15 | null |
| Z | 3 | 3 |

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you can make a list of lists, and take the difference between list_inner[n-1] and list_inner[n] and append it to a contintuity_list.append(diffenrece)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 
Is there an example of making the list of lists? And what's the logic in creating this list?

Answer (score 1):

update: found the answer

```
df = df.withColumn("index",monotonically_increasing_id())
w = Window.partitionBy("Person").orderBy("index")
df = df.withColumn("continuity", sum(when(col("delta") > 10,1).otherwise(0)).over(w))

#Add code to nullify continuity where delta>0

df.show()
```